# IntelliJ doesn't sees files in SVN repositories

Tags: java, intellij-idea, svn

As you can read from the title if I try to check out a project from SVN IntelliJ finds the directories, but they're empty. Obviously, there are files on those repos, but it simply doesn't see them. I also tried with CLion and it has the same problem, so I think it doesn't depend on the IDE but it's an SVN problem. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: CLion is a purposed version of IntellJ.  What about Eclipse and NetBeans?

Comment: I try to install Eclipse and SVN and I'll tell you

Comment: Yes Eclipse works properly, but I want to use IntelliJ, it worked until yesterday, I can't understand why today not

Comment: Do you have IntelliJ configuration files stored in SVN?  If yes, they may have been corrupted confusing IntelliJ.

Comment: I don't know bu I don't think so. I just downloaded SVN, set the path of svn.exe in bin directory and created the repository, as usual. I have the same problem with Ubuntu, installed on an external driver

Comment: Then just use SVN from the command line and edit with IntelliJ until you find out what the problem is.  You know you can use git to talk to a SVN server?

Comment: On which os does your inteliJ run? Under windows i was able to to talk to svn out of the box. On Ubunto i needed to manually install some certificates before it worked. Have you tried to "refresh the repository data? (In my current Ubuntu InelliJ Ultimate 2020.1 in the suvesion window under sub-tab "repository" is a refresh button)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, I didn't know it, I've never needed it.

Comment: @k3b I have either Windows and Kubuntu but on both of them SVN doesn't work anymore with IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.1. I've tried to refresh the repository but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Learn git.  It is much more powerful that subversion, and is nice to have on your resume.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I know, but unfortunately I'm a student and our professor wants us tu use Subversion, since that at the exam we'll have to commit the project there to have it corrected

Comment: In that case use exactly those tools suggested by your professor. Including ide.

Comment: Just a clarification. Does the working copy actually have the files? I mean, can you see them in Windows Explorer? The first step is to know if the problem is that you have a shallow working copy or that IntelliJ is ignoring certain objects.

Comment: I don't have a working copy because I need to check out a new project our professor gave us, but even with other projects I have here it doesn't work. It looks like a whole JetBrains problem, because it does like this with IntelliJ but also with DataGrip, Lion, PyCharm and Android Studio

Comment: It looks like it solved on its own, I don't know why

Comment: "I don't have a working copy because I need to check out a new project our professor gave us". That doesn't make sense. In Subversion, the check out operation is what creates a working copy.